# What is the correct word for an unopened product/box?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, adjectives

I am looking for two words or possibly one.

1. When a device like a cell phone or laptop has not been opened to be repaired. For example if you open its back panel, it looses its guarantee.
2. If you buy a device such as a brand new cell phone or TV, and you are the first person to open its box by cutting/tearing the seal, what is that called?

I can think of "a sealed box/phone; untouched, intact, security sticker, warranty void sticker,

Comment: The seal is called a tamper evident seal. The product is untampered with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unopened/Unused** is the designation for pristine product.

Collectibles are so designated :

> Brand New **Unopened/Unused** Product 110 Bulk Collectible

[Amazon (Pokemon)](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Unopened-Unused-Product-Collectible-Pokemon/dp/B00AXJIHDA)

This is also the designation of products lawfully destroyed under Health Policy :

> **Unopened, Unused** Prescription Drugs Destroyed at Taxpayer Expense

[Health Law](http://www.law.uh.edu/Healthlaw/perspectives/Food/001129Unopened.html)

It is also the designation used by retailers with regard to their returns policies :

> you may return any **unopened and unused** items to us within 14 days of receipt.

[Customer Services](https://customerservices.beautybay.com/hc/en-gb/articles/200030991-Returning-an-item)